# Vaadin Upgrade from 23.0.9 to 23.1.0 Changing Behaviour of Routing / sw.js

Tags: vaadin

I have an application that hosts both a REST endpoint and a Vaadin UI. I have two Servlets mapped:

- VaadinServlet - `/*`
- CustomServlet - `/rest/v1/*`

With version 23.0.9 of Vaadin whether I invoked the `/rest/v1/*` path, it would simply allow my request to go through to the CustomServlet.

With version 23.1.0 this no longer works. Basically when I now invoke the `/rest/v1/*` path after having opened the application, the Vaadin Flow Router seems to intercept the request and gives an error. This is due it would seem to changes in how the sw.js file is generated. I.e. if I manually unregister it for the 23.1.0 instance of the application, it does allow a direct request to `/rest/v1/*` to pass-through.

However, once I hit the main application page and the sw.js gets a chance to install, it stops working.

Is this a regression / bug with the new version?

Comment: Your case is probably related to https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13963

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround for this. Basically I set up my Vaadin Servlet like:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/ui/*","/VAADIN/*"}, name = "configurationServlet", asyncSupported = true)
public class WebAppConfigurationServlet extends VaadinServlet
{
}
```

And then all my routes I just drop the `ui/` prefix. I.e.

```
@Route(value = "about", layout = AdminMainLayout.class)
```

rather than

```
@Route(value = "ui/about", layout = AdminMainLayout.class)
```